# why UIScrollView doesnt call it's Delegate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

the problem is I make a new UIScrollView at Xib and then link the delegate to owner..
some how the delegate doesnt called.. any clue? or simple example for UIScrollView

sorry I am a new ios developer and thank in advance..

the code :

at header

```
@interface stageViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

at .m

```
#pragma mark drag delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
}                                              // any offset changes
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidZoom");
}

// called on start of dragging (may require some time and or distance to move)
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewWillBeginDragging");
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewWillEndDragging");
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
}
```

Comment: have you set the `UIScrollView`'s `delegate` property to `self`?

Comment: yes.. I already set it's delegate to self.. but still not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `scrollView.delegate = self;` If you have made it pragmatically.
And if you have your `ScrollView` in `XIB` then **ctrl+drag** from your `scrollView` to your `File's Owner` and then set its delegate.

Comment: Also, you may have trouble with delegate methods being called if you create your scrollView in Interface Builder, and init and alloc it your code as well. Either 1) Init the scrollView programmatically, then call `scrollView.delegate = self`, or 2) Create in IB, then link via the directions above.

Comment: I already do both of them.. but still not working.. I think that delegate have a bug.. or something like that, so I make my own scrollview with touch event.. LoL